# how i get out from the loop if switch case implemented(there is a switch inside the loop)

Tags: javascript

How I get out from the loop if switch-case implemented (there is a switch inside the loop).

```
function playInbestPlace() {
  console.log("hello from playInbestPlace ")
  findEmptyarea();
  for (var i = 0; i < indexOfEmpty.length; i++) {
    var elem = indexOfEmpty[i];
    switch (elem) {
      case 0:
        cells[elem].childNodes[0].append("o");
        break;
      case 2:
        cells[elem].childNodes[0].append("o");
        break;
      case 4:
        cells[elem].childNodes[0].append("o");
        break;
      case 6:
        cells[elem].childNodes[0].append("o");
        break;
      case 8:
        cells[elem].childNodes[0].append("o");
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

I want it to get out if any case valid.

Comment: the whole `switch` block is unnecessary

Comment: All that code and it could just be ? `if (elem%2 === 0) { cells[elem].childNodes[0].append("o"); break; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a flag variable to break from the loop when some condition is verified.

```
function playInbestPlace() {
  console.log("hello from playInbestPlace ");
  findEmptyarea();

  var keepOnLooping = true;

  for (var i = 0; keepOnLooping && i < indexOfEmpty.length; i++) {
    if (elem % 2 === 0) {
      cells[elem].childNodes[0].append("o");

      keepOnLooping = false;
    }
  }
}
```

I've also added epascarello optimization in my answer.

Comment: you can also use break statement better than flag

Comment: Yeah, it's the same. Using a flag is just a way of avoiding `break` instructions and storing the information that you exited the loop without checking all the array.

Answer (score 2):

you can add a variable `found` and break out of the loop if it's `true` :

```
function playInbestPlace() {
  console.log("hello from playInbestPlace ")
  findEmptyarea();
  for (var i = 0; i < indexOfEmpty.length; i++) {
    var elem = indexOfEmpty[i];

    var found = false; // initial found is false

    switch (elem) {
      case 0:
        cells[elem].childNodes[0].append("o");
        found = true;
        break;
      case 2:
        cells[elem].childNodes[0].append("o");
        found = true;
        break;
      case 4:
        cells[elem].childNodes[0].append("o");
        found = true;
        break;
      case 6:
        cells[elem].childNodes[0].append("o");
        found = true;
        break;
      case 8:
        cells[elem].childNodes[0].append("o");
        found = true;
        break;
    }

    if(found) // break out if it's true
        break;
  }
}
```